# Is the term "sambayón" accepted everywhere?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, sustantivos, comida, hispanoamérica

*Sabayón* (or *sambayón*) is an Italian dessert composed by eggs (only the yellow part), sugar and wine.

I was searching and at least in Argentine and Uruguay the two terms are correct. In the rest of South America, are the two terms accepted or is any of the terms more accepted than the other?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio, gbianchi! Para tus próximas miles de preguntas (ojalá :D) puedes utilizar tanto el castellano como el inglés, ambos idiomas se aceptan en el sitio.

Comment: Me costaron mucho los tags!!!! :p.. gracias @fedorqui ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DAMER suggests it is only used in Argentina and Uruguay:

> [**sambayón**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=sambay%C3%B3n). (Del it. *zabaione*).
>   I.  1.  m. *Ar, Ur.* Crema elaborada con yemas de huevo, vino y azúcar.

It probably has to do with its Italian origins and people from this country emigrating to both Argentina and Uruguay, but not the rest of South America.